# Sequelize - include all association filtered results

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a a model called Post and Country. When I filter by a particular country Id, it returns correctly filtered posts but only returns that specific country in the response and discards all the other countries associated with the Post. How can I include and retain all the countries associated with the post in the response?

Post.js

```
class Post extends Sequelize.Model {
    static init(sequelize, DataTypes) {
        return super.init(
            {
                id: {
                    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                    primaryKey: true,
                    autoIncrement: true
                },
                number: {
                    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                    validate: {
                        isInt: true
                    }
                },
         }
      );

      static associate(models) {
        this.myAssociation = this.belongsToMany(models.Country,
            {through: "CountriesImpacted", foreignKey: "id"});
      }
}

module.exports = Incident;
```

Country.js

```
class Country extends Sequelize.Model {
    static init(sequelize, DataTypes) {
        return super.init(
            {
                id: {
                    allowNull: false,
                    autoIncrement: true,
                    primaryKey: true,
                    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
                },
                name: {
                    type: Sequelize.STRING,
                    primaryKey: true,
                    unique: true
                }
            }, {sequelize, modelName: 'country', tableName: 'Countries'}
        )
    }
}

module.exports = Country;
```

routes.js

```
    Post.findAndCountAll({
        attributes: { exclude: ["createdAt", "updatedAt"] },
        order: [Country, "name", "asc"],
        include: [{
            model: Country,
            where: { id: country_ids_from_request }
        }],
        where: filters,
        distinct: true,
        offset: offset,
        limit: limit
    })
```

example output

```
{
  '0': {
    id: 1,
    number: 1203021,
    countries: [
      {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Australia',
        CountriesImpacted: {
          id: 1,
          countryId: 6
        }
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        name: 'New Zealand',
        CountriesImpacted: {
          id: 1,
          countryId: 7
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

when I filter by country id 6, the repsonse will discard New Zealand...

Answer (score 1):

It requires a sub-query to fetch the eligible `Post` model. It will look like following

```
return Post.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: Country
        }
    ],
    where: {
        id : {
            [Sequelize.Op.in] : [Sequelize.literal(`(SELECT posts.id FROM posts INNER JOIN countries ON countries.postId = posts.id WHERE ${COUNTRY_ID} IN (countries.id))`)] // Subquery...
        }
    }
})
```

Here i assume following

1. Your `Post` schema name is `posts`.
2. Your `Country` schema name is `countries`.
3. `Country` has a `postsId` foreign key `REFERENCES TO` `Post`.

If you are not comfortable with having sub-query inside your project while using **Sequelize (ORM)**, then you have to execute two query, first fetching all the eligible Posts then fetch desired for those Posts.